# Ajuda problema com Fração com java

Tags: java

Quero fazer o seguinte algoritmo:

```
300/15 + 350/14 - 400/13 + 450/12 - .....
```

Ou seja, quando o denominador é ímpar ele soma com o próximo resultado, se for par ele diminui.

Aqui está meu código, porém ele está me dando um resultado diferente das calculadoras:

```
// one class needs to have a main() method
public class HelloWorld {
    // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double numerador = 300.0;
        double resultado = 0.0;
        for (int i = 15; i > 0; i--) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                resultado = resultado - (numerador / i);
                System.out.println("s " + numerador);
                System.out.println(i);
                System.out.println(resultado);
            } else {
                resultado = (numerador / i) + resultado;
                System.out.println("d " + numerador);
                System.out.println(i);
                System.out.println(resultado);
            }
            numerador = numerador + 50;
        }

        System.out.println(resultado);
    }
}
```

Comment: Não encontrei nenhum erro no seu [programa](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/LsBVkYA7H9). Eu até testei a sequência no [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=300%2F15-350%2F14%2B400%2F13-450%2F12%2B500%2F11-550%2F10%2B600%2F9-650%2F8%2B700%2F7-750%2F6%2B800%2F5-850%2F4%2B900%2F3-950%2F2%2B1000) para ver se o resultado era o mesmo.

Mas tem algo estranho na sua sequência: se quando o denominador é ímpar ele soma (+) e quando é par subtrai (-), então porque o segundo termo 340/14 é positivo? Os sinais deveriam alternar...

Comment: Na pergunta você colocou a expressão `300/15 + 350/14 - 400/13 + 450/12...`, mas o código está fazendo `300/15 - 350/14 + 400/13 - 450/12 ...` - talvez seja esse o motivo da confusão.